# creating a drop down list in MVC5

Tags: c#, view, asp.net-mvc-5, html.dropdownlistfor

I am trying to create a drop down list but it gives me an error saying 'Cannot implicitly convert type 'string' to 'System.Web.Mvc.SelectList'. My code is below:

Application Database Model:

```
public string dropdown{ get; set; }
```

Application View Model:

```
public SelectList dropdown{ get; set; }
```

ApplicationService.cs:

```
 public static SelectList GetDropdownList(string currSelection)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> list = new List<SelectListItem>();
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "firstvalue" });
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "secondvalure" });
        list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "All of the Above" });


        return new SelectList(list, "Value", "Text", currSelection);
    }
```

in my controller i am calling:

```
 applicationviewmodel.dropdown= ApplicationService.GetDropdownList(null);

 and then trying to save it in database as:

 ApplicationDatabaseModel.dropdown= applicationviewmodel.dropdown;
```

This is where i get this error.

In my view i have:

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.dropdown, applicationviewmodel.dropdown)
```

I am not sure how to make this work.

Comment: What type is `ApplicationDatabaseModel.dropdown`? A `string`?

Comment: yes. its a model created from a database

Comment: Well, `ApplicationDatabaseModel.dropdown = applicationviewmodel.dropdown` says "Please assign a `SelectList` object to a `string`". This is where your issue is. How do you propose to store an entire `SelectList` instance inside a `string`? You need to think how you might do that.. the compiler won't do it for you.

Comment: is there any other way of creating a drop down list ?

Comment: Do you understand what the problem is with your code (how I just explained it)?

Comment: yes I do. would i need to change drop down in database model to a seleclist, but i dont know how that will work

Comment: I would need the value that has been assigned in the dropdown list to be passed in the database model. so get a selected string value from dropdown and then pass that to database model. but how would i do that..

Comment: I have added an answer. Hopefully it makes sense to you.

Answer (score 2):

I find it's easier to just have a List as part of your model and use a simple linq statement.  Simple example below for a countries drop down:

assuming you have a model like

```
public class MyModel()
{
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public List<Country> Countries { get; set; }
}
```

and a Country class of

```
public class Country()
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

in your view you can then do the following:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CountryId, 
                           Model.Countries.Select(x => 
                                new SelectListItem { Text = x.Name, Value = x.Id.ToString(), Selected = Model.CountryId == x.Id }, "Please Select...", null)
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.dropdown, applicationviewmodel.dropdown)
```

..is incorrect. It is trying to store the selected item into the `SelectList` instance.

What you want is a `string` variable on the view model that this value is selected into:

```
public class ApplicationViewModel {
    public SelectList DropDown { get; set; }
    public string SelectedDropDownValue { get; set; }
    // .. the rest of the properties here
}
```

Then your view becomes this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(x => x.SelectedDropDownValue, Model.DropDown)
```

This says "store the selected value into `SelectedDropDownValue`".

Then, you need to change how you build your `SelectList`. `Value` is what gets posted to your property.. `Text` is what is displayed in the browser.

So this:

```
list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "1", Text = "firstvalue" });
list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "2", Text = "secondvalure" });
list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "3", Text = "All of the Above" });
```

..has to be this:

```
list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "firstvalue", Text = "firstvalue" });
list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "secondvalue", Text = "secondvalure" });
list.Add(new SelectListItem { Value = "all of the above", Text = "All of the Above" });
```

..because they are strings (unless of course, you *want* the numbers to be posted back).

Then, finally, your controller code becomes this:

```
// assign the string value to the string property
ApplicationDatabaseModel.dropdown = applicationviewmodel.SelectedDropDownValue;
```

Comment: I have tried that but its giving me an error ' There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'model.selecteddropdownvalue'